# Need an example on including external cn1lib classes in another cn1lib

Tags: codenameone

Although cn1libs cannot be nested Shai Almog said that a first project can be created which uses the first cn1lib and referenced from the second. Is there a specific example on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have something like that actually running but you can probably just edit the the jar task in the cn1lib to also include the classes from the other cn1lib:

```xml
<target name="jar" depends="compile,Stubs">
    <ant inheritall="false" antfile="pathtoothercn1lib/build.xml" target="jar" />
    <copydir src="pathtoothercn1lib/build" to="build" />
   ...
</target>
```

Comment: I got it to work using a different technique. In my cn1lib I process a series of tasks managed by a static class. I wanted to add the new codescan library to replace my own which used a static picture analysis. I provided a public method to add a new task; library.addTask(UITask task); Then from the main application I added an anonymous class extending UITask and overrided the preform method and handling of the scan result. Works fine.